# is it possible to use predefined angularjs directives such as ng-repeat in comments style.?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, knockout.js, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Please let me know, whether comments style syntax is possible in angular js for directives such as ngRepeat ? 
I know KnockoutJS supports virtual elements such as below:

```
 <tr data-bind="foreach: data.Headings">
    <!-- ko if: $index()==0 --> <!--comment style syntax -->
    <th class="col-1">&nbsp;</th>
    <!--/ko-->
    <th data-bind="text: $data"></th>
 </tr>
```

I would like to know, whether it is possible to write such kind of code in angular js, I mean using comments like syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Even though comment syntax is relatively rare sometimes it's necessary to use exactly it because it's impossible to go with attribute or element notation: e.g. if element cannot be put in HTML in this position.

However, `ngRepeat` cannot be used as a comment. Directive declaration states restrict rule as attribute:

```
restrict: 'A'
```

Check the ngRepeat [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L317).

Comment: Just to clarify. When you write your own directives you decide what 'style syntax' is allowed. OP mentions ngRepeat which is core angular and that - for some reason - does not allow comments style usage.